# Is there any relationship between $Ax=b$ and $A^tx=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for any matrix $A$ the dimension of the column space equals the dimension of the row space.  However, I'm not sure if there's any relationship between the solutions of

$$A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$$

and the solutions of

$$A^t\vec{x}=\vec{b}$$

That is to say, if you know the solution of one equation, does that tell you anything about the solutions of the other?

Comment: Not when the right hand sides are the same. More generally, see the [Fredholm alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative#Linear_algebra).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any. This may not answer your question but I thought it is useful to state this:

Let $F = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax = b, x \geq 0 \}$

Then, exactly one the following holds:

- $F \neq \emptyset$ (a feasible solution exists)
- $\exists$ $y$ such that $A^T y \geq 0 $, $b^T y < 0$

Either there is a feasible solution $x$ OR there is a $y$ that certifies no such $x$ exists.

Comment: Does $x\geq 0$ mean that each coordinate is non-negative?

Comment: yes ......................